# Scilab fill matrice with loop

Tags: loops, scilab

I have this loop :

```
Nbcomp=floor(long/(2*dpas)+0.5);
xn=input("Voulez-vous modifier les éléments de compensations si oui tapé 1 sinon 0")
if xn==1  then 
    for ca=0:Nbcomp
    pas_pr1=(long-2*dpas)/(Nbcomp-1)
```

I want to putt all the result of pas_pr1 in a matrice.

```
    m = ones(Nbcomp,2)
    m1= m.*pas_pr1
   // m1=m*m2

end
elseif xn==0 then pas_pr=(long-2*dpas)/(Nbcomp-1);
end
```

So i did this but it's didnt work ... Anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear whether you want to put the values of `pas_pr1` into `m` or `m1`. But what you should do is change the loop to something like this:

```
pas_pr1=(long-2*dpas)/(Nbcomp-1)
matrix(ca+1) = pas_pr1
```

After computation, all the the values will be stored in `matrix`. The +1 there is needed because your loop starts counting from 0, and Scilab matrices' first index is 1, not zero.